# migration from xamarin.ios binding library to .net6-ios binding

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to update my xamarin.ios binding file to .net6-ios but when I am changing the runtime from .net7 to .net6 from the visual studio code ui it is not changing . What can I do here ? please help me out here . Is it possible

Comment: What do you mean UI is not changing? Have you checked this docs [Xamarin.iOS binding project migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/ios-binding-projects?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try to quit visual studio, make the changes and then reopen it? @srihari